# display data in alphabetical order iphone

Tags: iphone

How to display xml parsed Data in UITableView In alphabetical order.?

Comment: yeap i used sort description sir...... its working fine for my NSMutableArray .. for the static data... When i parsed xml data . my application get crashed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to display/arrange your data in alphabetical which in a array you have to use `NSSortDescriptor`

you  have to make the object of this `NSSortDescriptor` class and give data here which you are fetching from XML

```
NSSortDescriptor *itemXml = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"itemName" ascending:YES];
```

Now suppose you have an array   sortDescriptors

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:itemXml,nil];


[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Now give the yourArray to your `UITableView` delegate methods...... you will get the sorted data on table

Answer (score 4):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sorter;

sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"Category" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter];

[categoryListArray sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

[sorter release];
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are lots of different ways to sort arrays.

Sort descriptors are only one example.

Others are sortedArrayUsingComparator, sortedArrayUsingFunction:context, sortedArrayUsingSelector, and new to Mac OS 10.6 and iOS 4.0, sortedArrayWithOptions:usingComparator.

Those are NSArray methods that return a sorted array.

NSMutableArray also has variations on those methods that sort the mutable array "in place".