# How can I sort an NSMutableArray alphabetically? 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I want to sort an NSMutableArray alphabetically.

Comment: What is the type of the objects in the array?

Comment: I am storing an object in array that i want to sort the array with respect to object.name field

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can do this to sort NSMutableArray:

```
[yourArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Comment: [tempPeoples sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
i used this code it gives exception

Comment: can you plz post the exception statment.

Comment: NAddressBook[5197:207] *** -[AddressData localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x149160
2011-01-18 17:01:14.470 NAddressBook[5197:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AddressData localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x149160'
2011-01-18 17:01:14.484 NAddressBook[5197:207] Stack: (

Comment: Maybe the objects are not of type NSString... Edit: Yes :-)

Comment: ok good its not string ,problem is that I am storing object in array that object contains a field as name I want to sort array with respect to that

Comment: Mine is array of a string. But still crashes.

Answer (score 48):

The other answers provided here mention using @selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)
This works great for an array of NSString, however the OP commented that the array contains objects and that sorting should be done according to object.name property.

In this case you should do this:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

Your objects will be sorted according to the name property of those objects.

Comment: This is the better answer for this specific question. Works great!

Comment: Ha ha! Still a great answer 10 years later! Cocoa and Objective-C FTW!

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]; // Describe the Key value using which you want to sort. 
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:valueDescriptor]; // Add the value of the descriptor to array.
sortedArrayWithName = [yourDataArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors]; // Now Sort the Array using descriptor.
```

Here you will get the sorted array list.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest scenarios, if you had an array of strings:

```
NSArray* data = @[@"Grapes", @"Apples", @"Oranges"];
```

And you wanted to sort it, you'd simply pass in nil for the key of the descriptor, and call the method i mentioned above:

```
NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:nil ascending:YES];
data = [data sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[descriptor]];
```

The output would look like this:

```
Apples, Grapes, Oranges
```

For more details check [this](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/stevez/posts/ios-objective-c-sorting-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `NSSortDescriptor` class and rest you will get every thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612163/display-data-in-alphabetical-order-iphone/4612372#4612372)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Name_your_key_value" ascending:YES];
NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]; 
NSArray * sortedArray;
sortedArray = [Your_array sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

```
[myNSMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES],[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES]]];
```

All is acording to NSSortDescriptor...