# Objective-C, Sorting an NSMultable array of type class, alphabetically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, dropbox

I'm trying to sort a property on a type of a mutable array.
However I've only managed to sort a NSString array.

```
NSMutableArray<DBFILESFileMetadata*> *tmpArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (DBFILESMetadata *entry in entries)
{
    //conditions
    [tmpArray addObject:fileMetadata];
}
```

Here's the type / class

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-obj-c/blob/4c99bdf726cf9724adfddc19e71a87a6012eddeb/Source/ObjectiveDropboxOfficial/Shared/Generated/ApiObjects/Files/Headers/DBFILESMetadata.h

I've tried

```
[yourArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

and

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
[yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
```

The property is called name.

I've seen answer like this [How can I sort an NSMutableArray alphabetically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723697/how-can-i-sort-an-nsmutablearray-alphabetically/4723773)  but I can't seem to get this to work for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to sort using sortUsingSelector you need to implement your compare method in the objects that you are trying to compare. (So your `DBFILESMetadata` class would need a compare method - `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` in the code above.)

You should be able too use a sort descriptor as you show in your second attempt. What happens when you do that?

A third way to do it is to use the `NSMutableArray` `sortUsingComparator` and write an `NSComparator` block that compares the 2 objects.

I'm out of practice with Objective-C but a quick Google search found an example, which I adapted to your specific problem:

```
[entries sortUsingComparator:
  ^NSComparisonResult(DBFILESMetadata *obj1, DBFILESMetadata *obj2)
  {
     return [obj1.name localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare: obj2.name];
  }];
```

That should work, although as I say I'm out of practice in Objective-C, and its block syntax is pretty awkward and counter-intutive.

Comment: See the edit to my answer. I cleaned up a type in my comments, and also changed the code I provided to sort your objects using `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare` as you show in your code.