# How to reorder elements (NSString) of an NSArray alphabetically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsarray

How to reorder elements (NSString) of an NSArray alphabetically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use sortDescriptor

```
 NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"yourKey" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];
NSArray * sortedArray =
    [yourArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptor];
```

Answer (score 6):

**NSSortDescriptor** is overkill to sort an array whose elements are just **NSString** instances.

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [unsortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

If, instead of a new array instantiated with its elements sorted, you want to have the elements of an **NSMutableArray** instance reordered, there's a method for that:

```
[unsortedMutableArray sortUsingSelector: @selector(compare:)];
```

Use an **NSSortDescriptor** instance when you have a large object managing the array for you, like an NSArrayController or an NSTableView. If that's the case, and the elements are just instances of **NSString**, @iHS's answer would be correct.

Comment: I second this. However, if you do use an NSSortDescriptor, you can use @"", @"self" or even @"description" as the sort key for an array of NSString. But why not use the Apple-given compare: for this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use NSSortDescriptor class for sorting purposes

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortDesc = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@”self” ascending:YES];
[array sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDesc]];
[sortDesc release];
```

For More information, have a look at

1) [NSSortDescriptor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

2) [Sorting-NSArrays](http://thoughts.digital-transience.com/2009/03/sorting-nsarrays/comment-page-1/)

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it Try Using `NSSortDescriptor` take help from already ask [**Display data in alphabetical order iphone**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612163/display-data-in-alphabetical-order-iphone/4612372#4612372)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0:

categories is an array of Category -> [Category].

```
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true, selector: #selector(NSString.caseInsensitiveCompare(_:)))                                                  
let orderedCategories = (categories as NSArray).sortedArray(using: [sortDescriptor])
```

Replace category with your custom object array.  If you are using a regular NSArray, replace the `(categories as NSArray)` with your array.