# Sort the list items in A to Z order

Tags: iphone, objective-c, list

I have list of items and want to sort them in A to Z order like Contact list does. Could anyone please help me to understand how to do this? Any documentation on this would be appreaciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a `UITableView`?

Comment: please post an example of the code / approach you've tried so far

Comment: @Jim: Yep, I am using UITableView. Basically I can sort the items using standard sorting algorithm and show them but I want to display them like Contacts list does so that user can directly go to particular alphabet.                                                                    @TrickWallet: I have used standard Bubble sort algorithm and displayed the sorted items in UITableView. I am sure there must be some control supported by Apple that I can use directly but not getting there.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display/arrange your data in alphabetical order which in a array you have to use `NSSortDescriptor`there is a core data tutorial in the `devlopers` document of X-Code and here it is [coreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) and its a best one try to take help from there see how they are displaying the data in alphabetical order also refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612163/display-data-in-alphabetical-order-iphone/4612372#4612372).

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByName= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO selector:@selector(compareName:)];
if(sortByName)
{
    [yourArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByName]];
    [sortByUnlockLevel release];
}
```

And in your modal implement the method compareName

```
- (NSComparisonResult)compareName:(id)inObject
{
    NSComparisonResult result = NSOrderedSame;
    result = [Object.mName compare:self.mName]; 
    return result;
}
```